# git push . HEAD: Invalid remote name ".". Error: failed to push some refs to '.'

Tags: git

after creating a new branch via:

```
git checkout upstream
git checkout -b branch
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream
git push . HEAD
```

I see this error:

```
$ git push -u . HEAD
Invalid remote name ".": Invalid remote name: "."
error: failed to push some refs to '.'
```

Any ideas on how I can push to my repo while tracking the upstream?

Comment: `.` is your own repository. It makes no real sense to use `git push -u .` here, you can just run `git branch --set-upstream-to=<localbranch>` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind - just figured it out. I think . is being interpreted not as origin but as the local filesystem directory.

You have to do a 
'git push origin HEAD'